# Baggage re-checkin while in transit at Narita Airport

Tags: transit, japan, layovers, nrt

I am an Indian citizen, travelling from New Delhi to San Diego with Japan Airlines, with a 10-hour layover at Narita International Airport, Tokyo. Since I have a friend who wants to meet me there, I was thinking of getting a transit visa, so that I can meet him during that long transit time.

However, will I need to collect my bags and check them in again, in case I go out through immigration and come back before my flight time?

Answer (score 5):

**No**, you don't need to recheck your bags.

If they've been checked through to San Diego in Delhi, they will be placed in a holding area at Narita and will be moved straight onto your connecting flight without you needing to do anything.  Whether you go through immigration or stay airside makes no difference.